# Boto - Grab most recent from S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

I have got a bit out my depth. I want to store backups on S3 and then I am trying to download a script when downloads the most lastest modified file within a specific "folder" of an S3 bucket.

I got this far:

```
import boto
s3conn = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3conn.lookup('my_bucket_name')
for key in bucket:
  print k.name, k.last_modified

key.getfile()
```

So far, this is designed to to get the name and last modified of each file in the bucket. This is where I get stuck really, because I need to get the most recent and then download that, and that is where I am stuck.

Would anyone be able to offer a helping hand?

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort your list of keys by last_modifed, then the last item of the list will be the file you want. Something like this:

```
key_list = bucket.list()
key_list.sort(cmp = lambda x, y:
    cmp(x.last_modified, y.last_modified))
key_list[-1].get_file(destination_fp)
```

Here's another approach to sorting you could try:

```
key_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.last_modified)
```

Comment: You don't have to convert the timestamp strings to a time object or a DateTime.  They are ISO8601 date strings and they will sort just fine as strings.

Comment: How would you do this without the conversion? Would it be this?
https://gist.github.com/4242333

Comment: No, last_modified is an attribute of each key in your list. I already edited my answer to take out the unnecessary converstion.

Comment: You could also use [``operator.attrgetter``](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) instead of a lambda function. Something like ``from operator import attrgetter; key_list.sort(key=attrgetter('last_modified'))`` should work. See also [this Python wiki page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Operator_Module_Functions).

Comment: Thank you both for the help. Is it right that these are the three options, and is there one which stands out as being more suitable?https://gist.github.com/4242515

Comment: They'll all work, so I'd recommend picking whichever happens to be easiest for you to understand. That way it will be easy to pick up on what you were doing if you have to come back to this in six months or a year.

Comment: Did something change with boto?  I'm getting ```AttributeError: 'BucketListResultSet' object has no attribute 'sort'```